# Why Image attribute is not working in JSX

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx

```
<Image loading="lazy" src="/assets/blog/image.webp" alt="image photo" width="867" height="1300" style={{ maxWidth: '500px' }} />
```

maxWidth is not working in JSX.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you have applied `width="867"` to the `component` which overrides `style={{ maxWidth: '500px' }}` the `maxWidth` specified in the `inline css`.

Remove `width="867"` attribute from the `component` and try using the below code:

```
<Image ... height="1300" style={{ maxWidth: '500px', width: '..px' }} />
```

Comment: If I remove the width then it will throw an error as the width is not defined in the Image element of nextJS. 
Error: Image with src "/assets/blog/image.webp" must use "width" and "height" properties or "layout='fill'" property.

Comment: I'm not telling you to completely remove it just specify it in the `style`

Comment: Is your `Image` component expecting a `width` prop ?

Comment: You can see the error that occurred above.

Comment: Try this `style={{ maxWidth: '500px !important' }}`

Comment: Nopes, not worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
<Image 
 loading="lazy"
 src="/assets/blog/image.webp"
 alt="image photo"
 height={1300}
 style={{ maxWidth: '500px',width:"100%" }}
/>
```

This should work.

Comment: Not working because layout fill is stretching the image and made it so funny.

Comment: Is it working now ?

Comment: nope, it's not working